# Putting $n$ balls into $n$ boxes, what is the expected value of the number of balls that are in the right boxes?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following probability question, with two different solutions, and I would like to determine which one is right. Here is the problem:

$n$ balls are labeled $1$ to $n$, and $n$ boxes are also labeled $1$ to $n$. Now put these $n$ balls randomly into these $n$ boxes, such that each box contains only one ball. If a ball is in the box with the same number it has (e.g. ball #3 is in box #3), then we say that this ball is in the right box. Let $X$ be the number of balls that are in the right boxes, what is the expected value of $X$?

Here are the two solutions I have:

**Solution 1:** The probability that at least $k$ balls are in the right box is
$$P(X\ge k)=\frac{\binom{n}{k}(n-k)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{k!},\quad k=0,1,2,\dots,n,$$
so the expected value of $X$ is

$$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^n P(X\ge k)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}.$$

**Solution 2:** For $j=1,\dots,n$, let $X_j$ be the random variable such that
$$X_j=\begin{cases}1, &\text{if ball }\#j\text{ is in the right box},\\
0, &\text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$
Then we have $X=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$. For each $j=1,\dots,n$, we have
$$P(X_j=1)=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n},$$
therefore,
$$E(X)=\sum_{j=1}^n E(X_j)=1.$$

From my instinct, I feel that the first solution is the right one, but I cannot tell what is wrong with the second solution (Maybe I am wrong?). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Now I've figured out that the second one is right. The problem with the first one is that the relation **$P(X\ge k)=\frac{\binom{n}{k}(n-k)!}{n!}$** is incorrect, and thus caused the wrong answer.

Comment: The second is the correct one. I don't quite get the probability calculation in the first. It is impossible to have only one incorrect, so $P(X=n-1)=0$, and your probability is not compatible with that.

Comment: $P(X\ge 1)\neq\frac{1}{1!}=1$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I see, this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks. Now I see where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution is the right one. What was your thinking process when claiming that $\mathbb{P}(X \ge k) = \frac{{{n}\choose{k}} (n-k)!}{n!}$ ?

Comment: $n!$ is the total number of combinations. Now assume that at least $k$ balls are in the right box, this means in particular, $k$ balls are in the right box, and that's where the factor $\binom{n}{k}$ came from. Now for the rest of the $(n-k)$ balls, they are permuted in any order (in the rest of the $(n-k)$ boxes), and this gives the factor $(n-k)!$. This was the initial thought.

Comment: @FrankLu With that counting method, many cases are overcounted. For example, if k=1 and there are actually two correct balls, then either one of the correct balls can be the chosen correct one with the other being part of the n-1 remaining "don't care" balls.

Comment: ok @FrankLu. But at least means either k or k+1 or k+2 or ... or n. Then when dealing with the case "k ball are in the right box" you omit several cases

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You are right, this is where the problem arises.

Comment: @ChristianYeo Right, I messed up with counting those cases.